# complete java class library source code on osx

Tags: java, macos

I've got the incomplete sources, courtesy of the official JDK download from apple. Its missing things like com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl, which is of course what I need to step into.

Is there a convenient source jar available? I found one for b14, but the sources for that file don't match.

I went and got the OpenJDK sources (b25 is latest apparently) but it would appear to need a bunch of other things downloaded and then assembled and I'm loath to attempt that on OSX.

The OSX version claims to be 1.6.0_33.

Comment: Have you tried getting the new one from Oracle? They have just started offering official Mac downloads (only JDK7, only for Lion) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Ah. That would be nice. I'm JDK6 and Snow Leopard unfortunately. Does JDK7 have the "non public" sources in its src.jar?